# Android studio Call method

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem with my code.
I have an activity with an `EditText` , when the activity opens for the first time I would like to pass the value of the `EditText` to my server and receive an answer.

The problem is if I call the method in `onCreate ()` it does not work.

If instead I call the method from the 
 `click ()`
event of the `button` it works.

Is there a way to call the method from the `onCreate ()` and display the contents of the `EditText`?

This is my code :

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

     First_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText50);

     parseContent = new ParseContentRistoratore(this);
     preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelperRistoratore(this);

     CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

     UserRegisterFunction(F_Name_Holder);

     prova = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
     // If EditText is not empty and CheckEditText = True then this block will execute.
     prova.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
         }
     });
 }

 //REGISTRATION
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
 public void UserRegisterFunction(final String fk_id_ristorante){
     class UserRegisterFunctionClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
             super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Prova gratuita terminata")){
                //  finish();  con finish(); l'attività finisce
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Versione_scaduta.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        //REGISTRATION
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            hashMap.put("fk_id_ristorante",params[0]);
            finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURLRegister);
            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    UserRegisterFunctionClass userRegisterFunctionClass = new UserRegisterFunctionClass();
    userRegisterFunctionClass.execute(fk_id_ristorante);
}

//REGISTRAZIONE
public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){
    F_Name_Holder = First_Name.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(F_Name_Holder) )
    {
        CheckEditText = false;
    }
    else {
        CheckEditText = true ;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Account account) {
            //editUserId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUserEmail);
            // editUserId.setText(String.format("Email Id %s",account.getEmail()));

            First_Name.setText(String.format("r%s", account.getId()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {
        }
    });
}

}
```

If you can not do it, I'd like to know something else instead.

Why in my `PHP` code if I remove the `Else` from the `IF Cycle` the code does not work when it is started on `Android studio`?

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'config.php'; 

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 $fk_id_ristorante = $_POST['fk_id_ristorante'];



 $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM R_Iscrizioni WHERE data_scadenza < CURDATE() AND fk_id_ristorante='$fk_id_ristorante' AND pagamento = 'No' ";

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));

 if(isset($check)){

 echo 'Prova gratuita terminata';
}
else {
echo 'Hello';
}
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Try putting timer in `onCreate()` .

Comment: Excuse me for what do I need the timer?

Comment: You said that your code works fine if you put that in click() event , so instead of doing that onClick() give system some time for being ready and execute code properly Mr.

Comment: Check out Activity life cycle and fragment life cycle

Comment: Thanks for the advice, after I will try to set up a Timer and see if it works.

Comment: But if I did not want to display the If cycle's Echo of the PHP file, how could I do?

Comment: Move your code at "onResume()". Check out the Activity lifecycle for more information

Comment: If I move the method calls to onResume () the code does not work

Comment: @VrushiPatel Thank you so much it works perfectly with the timer.

Comment: If you answer me the question you sign it as the right answer :)

Comment: @SimoneBruziches Sure will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is just use `CountDownTimer` to let system load and be ready to let your code be execute right way.

Hope this helped you.